# Styling Pandas dataframe within streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, styles, streamlit

I am looking to create my own style conditions based on two functions: I want a background color and size row_height .

For that I defined 2 styles functions

```
def resistance(s):
     color='#fcdcdc' if s.interpretation=='Resistant' else ''
     return ['background-color: {}'.format(color)]*len(s)
def null_row(s):
     size=1px if s.interpretation=='' else size=12px
     return ['line-height: {}'.format(color)]*len(s)

df_style=df.style.\
     apply(resistance,axis=1).\
     apply(height,axis=1)
                       
st.table(df_style)
st.dataframe(df_style)
```

Except that line_height is never changed for empty rows and seems not working (with no error message). The same when i take an arbitrary not null conditions or try to size every row-height on 1px.

is it an issue with streamlit or with my code?

Thanks for help

Comment: Can you share a more complete code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation for pd.style.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html), the styling function needs to return actual data and not only formatting instruction.

> func - function
>
> func should take a Series if axis in [0,1] and return a list-like object of same length, or a Series, not necessarily of same length,
> with valid index labels considering subset. func should take a
> DataFrame if axis is None and return either an ndarray with the same
> shape or a DataFrame, not necessarily of the same shape, with valid
> index and columns labels considering subset.

The example code is this:

```
def highlight_max(x, color):
    return np.where(x == np.nanmax(x.to_numpy()), f"color: {color};", None)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 2), columns=["A", "B"])
df.style.apply(highlight_max, color='red')  
df.style.apply(highlight_max, color='blue', axis=1)  
df.style.apply(highlight_max, color='green', axis=None)
```

You need to adapt your functions to what you want to achieve and return the data you actually want to format.

The correct attribute to use is `height` instead of `line-height`.

You have a different name for your `null_row` function than what you are calling: `height`.

Unfortunately, it is a lot harder to address whole rows and Streamlit also does not respect all CSS styling parameters (see the hide index topic). Thus, I am not sure it's possible to set row height to 1px. Would it be feasible to remove the row from the displayed dataframe? For that you could do `df[df["interpretation"] == ""]`.

If I understand what you want to do correctly, this should be the correct code:

```
def resistance(x, color):
    return np.where(x=='Resistant', f"background-color: {color};", None)

def null_row(x):
    return np.where(x=='', "height: 12px;", "height: 1px;")

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["interpretation"], data=[[""], ["Resistant"], [""], ["Resistant"]])
df_style = df.style.apply(resistance, color='#fcdcdc').apply(null_row)
                   
st.table(df_style)
```